# Displaying Single page application view as an iFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor, single-page-application, durandal

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) developed using Durandal and ASP.net MVC. The SPA has quite a few views and view models. I have a view `Test.html` that displays some data based on `Id`.

Now, I have another web application which is not SPA. I want the to display the view, `Test.html`, as an iFrame in this application and display the data by passing the `Id` from this second application.

Any idea as to how this can be achieved? 
Do I need to create separate views - one for my SPA and another for iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need another view. Just point your iframe source to your spa application location with required parameters, for example:

```
<iframe src="http://myspa.com/#Test/123"></iframe>
```

Now, in your spa you just implement the `Test/:id` route as you need.

Comment: if I want to have user authentication implemented in my SPA view for iFrame, what is the best method you would suggest? Handling in the ViewModel or separately via MVC Controller?